# Access DOM element on a page in vue chrome extension

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension that will inject a content script only on a certain pages.
I'm using vue.js and I want to access some DOM elements of the pages, how I can achieve this?
Normally in jQuery I will have `$('.selector')` to access a dom element, but in this case I can't assign refs or any other id to the DOM elements I want to access. will `getElementById` work or there is another way?

Comment: Have a look at [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). These selector functions are really similar to the jQuery `$('')` selector

Comment: I need to try. Can I use it inside the mounted method?

Comment: Yes, you can use it in the mounted hook

Comment: @ValeriiVoronkov tested, but not working as expected, I'm only able to access my popup.html component DOM, not the one of the page